# Adding a toggle option to save dialog

Tags: add-on, customization

I'm trying to solve the [slow saving to network drives in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149926/saving-blend-files-straight-to-server-nets-0-5-speed-of-a-windows-file-copy-ho).
The reason it's so slow is the way Blender handles saving internally.

I found a solution that works by saving the file to a proxy location (temp dir) and then moving it to the network directory.

I'd like to add a checkbox to the **save file dialog** and the **save & load preferences** panels, just like the compression option.

I can't seem to find how to implement these toggle buttons on that location in 2.80

I thought I could find the buttons at `bpy.context.preferences.` but they don't seem to be there.

Can someone add an example of the code to add a toggle to these panels?

The gist of the code is this:

```
def execute(self, context):
    outname = bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath)
    outpath = os.path.dirname( bpy.path.abspath( bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.temporary_directory ) )
    outpath_final = os.path.dirname(bpy.path.abspath(bpy.data.filepath))
    print(os.path.join(outpath, outname))
    report = bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=os.path.join(outpath, outname),
                check_existing=True, copy=True)

    # os.rename(os.path.join(outpath, outname), os.path.join(outpath_final, outname)) # Does not work accross devices
    shutil.move(os.path.join(outpath, outname), os.path.join(outpath_final, outname))
    return report
```

Comment: Go to the location you want to add them in the UI, right-click and choose *Edit Source*