# Delayed reads/writes from external drive from blender 3.4.1

Tags: performance

### Computer Specs

New M2-8core gpu, MB Air, Ventura 13.2, 16gb ram,256gb ssd.
New external LaCie, self-powered D2 Pro 4tb drive. Rated and verified at 256mbs transfer rates. This is directly connected via USB-C/4. Blender 3.4.1

### Problem

Within Blender, any access of the external drive results in 15-30 second delays before the operation is completed and the beachball goes away. Some longer than that.

Both Apple and Seagate (LaCie owners) have failed to provide any insight, just circular finger pointing.

Was there something I should have configured or setup to optimize this?

Any shared experiences or advice would be great. I am a producing 3D modeler, creating 3D printed artwork

Comment: Probably the same as this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149926/saving-blend-files-straight-to-server-nets-0-5-speed-of-a-windows-file-copy-ho

Comment: Duarte, very helpful.  I am considering keeping working projects on my internal ssd and then doing some housekeeping/archiving once completed. The issue is of course exacerbated by the new Asset Browser feature in 3.x. It wants all the .blender files with assets to be kept somewhere that Blender knows about it.